# Is there a place to set a 'global' flash messages in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I'm quite happy setting flash messages in the controller like this:

```
redirect_to root_path, error: 'This is a highly eloquent and specialised error message just for you, my iridescent, transcendent and all round marvellous bundle of joy! You are not allowed in here you cheeky chappy, you!'
```

however, I find I'm doing a lot of copy paste when it comes to writing feature specs to test that these messages are being rendered:

```
context 'when user has eaten all the pies' do
   let(:cheeky) { FactoryGirl.build(:cheeky_user) }
   subject { page }

   before do
     log_in cheeky
     click_link 'steal pies'
   end

   it_should_behave_like 'home page'
   it{ should have_selector('.error', text: 'This is a highly eloquent and specialised error message just for you, my iridescent, transcendent and all round marvellous bundle of joy! You are not allowed in here you cheeky chappy, you!') }
end
```

It can be a pain when an assertion fails because I'm missing a character, but more so, when a get a bunch of failing specs because I've tweaked some error messages.

Testing error messages this closely may be an example of a brittle spec, but I want to test the correct error message is being shown.

I'd really like to be able to do this:

```
#somewhere in rails
ERROR_MSG_23 = 'This is a highly eloquent and specialised error message just for you, my iridescent, transcendent and all round marvellous bundle of joy! You are not allowed in here you cheeky chappy, you!'

#controller
redirect_to root_path, error: ERROR_MSG_23

#spec
context 'when user has eaten all the pies' do
   let(:cheeky) { FactoryGirl.build(:cheeky_user) }
   subject { page }

   before do
     log_in cheeky
     click_link 'steal pies'
   end

   it_should_behave_like 'home page'
   it{ should have_selector('.error', text: ERROR_MSG_23 ) }
end
```

Is there a gem for this? Or can this be implemented in vanilla rails?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `I18n`, like this:

en.yml:

```
en:
  flash_messages:
    message_1: 'This is a highly eloquent and specialised error message just for you, my iridescent, transcendent and all round marvellous bundle of joy! You are not allowed in here you cheeky chappy, you!'
```

controller:

```
redirect_to root_path, error: t('flash_messages.message_1')
```

spec:

```
it{ should have_selector('.error', text: I18n.t('flash_messages.message_1') }
```